# TensorBoard event files not updating in google drive

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I use google colab for training my model. I use tensorflow 2.2.

Here is how I create summary writer:

```
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(os.path.join(model_dir, 'logs'), max_queue=1)
```

Here is my code which I run each step:

```
with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar("train_loss", total_loss, step=num_steps)
    writer.flush()
```

The problem is that if model_dir is just /content/model_dir, then everything saves fine, but if I save my model to a folder on google drive (I connect to my google drive with this code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive2', force_remount=True)
```

) then event file doesn't get updated. It is being created, but it is not filling with data during training (and even after training is finished).

As I understand, the problem is that google drive doesn't understand that tensorflow updates the event file. But after training is finished, the whole event file is saved. What can I do to fix this bug?

Comment: I've experienced this issue multiple times, and I still don't know what causes it. For me it is either the event files "seem" to not update or they "seem" to not be created at all. It happens sometimes but not other times. By chance, I figured out a way to get around it. Just download the directory, and the files will show up in the downloaded zip file. Hence why I described the issue as "seem". I think Google Drive understand just fine that TensorFlow updates the event files, but something prevents the files from appearing properly sometimes.

Comment: OK, thank you for this workaround!